# Php code to check if file without and extention is really a directory or file

Tags: php

I want to check the file extension of in a root directory and also check if any folder or image but i have a problem when user upload a file that has not extension an show that it is a folder and file will not open because is actually not a folder.

Example user uploaded a file named `Makefile` and inside the make file it contain coffee script code like this

`WORKER_JS_TARGET = build/worker.js
WORKER_JS_SOURCES = \
    src/js/json2.js \
    src/js/worker.coffee.js \
//and more.....`

And in the same directory he also have folder named `Loader` and file `box.php` so now **Loader** show as folder and is okay, **box.php** show as file and is okay but **Makefile** show as folder but is not a folder what can i do?

```
<?php
$filename = 'datafile'
$extn=pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Prettifies file type
switch ($extn){

case "txt": $extn="Text File"; break;
case "log": $extn="Log File"; break;
case "htm": $extn="HTML File"; break;
case "html": $extn="HTML File"; break;
case "xhtml": $extn="HTML File"; break;
case "shtml": $extn="HTML File"; break;
case "php": $extn="PHP Script"; break;
case "js": $extn="Javascript File"; break;
case "css": $extn="Stylesheet"; break;

default: if($extn!=""){
$extn = strtoupper($extn)." File";
} else if(!is_dir($name)){
$extn = "Other"; // After i pass this condition to check if is dir it show both Makefile and Loader as Other
}else if(is_dir($name)){
$extn = "Directory";
} else{
$extn = "Unknown";
} break;
}
?>
```

Any idea on how to do this work fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this piece of code you checking the variable `$name` instead of `$filename` from what I can get from the given context.

```
} else if(!is_dir($name)){ //should be $filename
$extn = "Other"; 
}else if(is_dir($name)){ //should be $filename
$extn = "Directory";
} else{
```